# After downloading a base box to ~/.vagrant.d, does Vagrant alter the files there?

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant

I was assuming that the base boxes in .vagrant.d would remain pretty much as they were when you downloaded, them, and that any changes to your running VM would only be reflected in VirtualBox's files, but I altered my `lucid32` to `lucid32_backup`, and did a new `vagrant box add lucid32 http://files.vagrantup.com/lucid32.box` to get a new `lucid32` directory in `.vagrant.d`.  Then I did a diff of the files, and there were numerous differences in the XML files (box.ovf), and the binary files (box-disk1.vmdk) were different as well.

Why would the files in .vagrant.d/lucid32/ have changed?

Am I misunderstanding how they are used?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you're drawing the wrong conclusion.  I don't think your local Vagrant altered the base box after download.

Rather, they probably altered (regenerated) the box on the server.  This could have been for a configuration change or to pre-load it with the latest packages.

The more time elapsed since the box was freshly made, the longer:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

takes (due to updates).